# objects's size in the app doesnt match for every device

Tags: android

I have built a snake game, I used a canvas to draw the snake, the walls and the food.

and the sizes of the objects are not the same when i use it on differenet devices.

I have tried using this:

`final float scale = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;`

but its still different, less then what it was before, but still different.

here it is on a **htc one x** device:----------------------    here it is on a **pomp w89** device:

[image]  ---[image]

(the device kind doest really matter because its alse different on the emulator on my computer)

**the code:**

```
final float scale = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float PART_SIZE= 10*scale;

this.a=new Arena(view,PART_SIZE,33,36,1,0);
```

Arena Class:

```
public static int left;
public static int top;
public static int right;
public static int bottom;
public Arena(LinearLayout view,float snakePartSize,int width,int height,int top,int left) {
    //constructor
    WALL_SIZE=snakePartSize;
    this.left=(int) (view.getLeft()+(top*snakePartSize));
    this.top=(int) (0+(top*snakePartSize));
    this.right=(int) (this.left+(snakePartSize*width));
    this.bottom=(int) (this.top+(snakePartSize*height));
}
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    /*draws the walls
     * 
     */
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    leftW.setR(left, top, (int) (left+WALL_SIZE), bottom);
    topW.setR(left, top,right,(int) (top+WALL_SIZE));
    rightW.setR(right, top, (int) (right+WALL_SIZE),(int) (bottom+WALL_SIZE));
    bottomW.setR(left, bottom,(int)  (right+WALL_SIZE),(int) (bottom+WALL_SIZE));

    canvas.drawRect(leftW.getR(),leftW.getP());
    canvas.drawRect(topW.getR(),topW.getP());
    canvas.drawRect(rightW.getR(),rightW.getP());
    canvas.drawRect(bottomW.getR(),bottomW.getP());
    }
```

How can i fix it? Thanks